# Azure instance change code roll back

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure

I am new to Azure, I have small instance of cloud service, In last one week my instance is changed 2 times & all my project data is lost, it will roll back to 1 month older. All my client data is lost, Is there any way to  recover that data & why this issue occurs.

Comment: Whey you say all your client data is lost, what do you mean? code that you had on the instance? or data such as upload files or local database?

Comment: all uploaded files from browser are lost, as well as my code also rolled back to 1 month older.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to recover your data and there's no way to prevent this from happening. This is by design.

Whenever your machine crashes or there's an update to the system, it is completely wiped. A new system image will be copied, the machine will boot again and your application is copied over. Azure cloud services are Platform-as-a-Service (PaaS).

This leaves you with two possible options. The first would be to not store persistent data on the cloud service in the first way. This is no proper way for Azure Cloud Services. Instead store your data in the Azure Storage or an Azure SQL database (or wherever you like).

Another option would be to use a virtual machine instead of a cloud service. That machine is completely in your hand. It's your duty to update it, keep it secure and to do whatever it takes to keep it running. With this approach you also have to take care yourself about a loadbalancer, about multiple instances, etc, so outscaling becomes a lot more hard. This is Infrastructure-as-a-Service (IaaS).

So it actually depends on what you want to do.

Comment: but my code is also rolled back to one month older, How can i prevent this or where to upload code so new server will start by that code like AMI in AWS

Comment: How did you update your code? Did you connect to your machine and overwrote the files, or did you upload a new azure package?

Comment: By using Visual Studio 2010 Publish option. We deploy (Web Deploy) our code after every change.

Comment: That's the problem. Web Deploy connects to a machine and replaces the files directly. This would be a suitable method for an Azure WebSite or possible also for a virtual machine. For Cloud Services it does not work, because it will (as you noticed) rollback to the actual Azure Package. Also Web Deploy does not work with Cloud Services if the instance count is above 1 (which is the entire point of cloud services, and with count 1 you do not get the SLA). You rather should right click on your Azure project and click deploy there.

Comment: Can you suggest what should I use for my project I am working on C# .Net web application. which is under beta release & currently we are making frequent changes according to client requirement.

Comment: What do you need? Just an online web server? Do you need to be able to out-scale your application as the demand increases? Or do you just need a virtual machine?

Comment: As I mention that application is in beta phase so no heavy load this time, but we also maintain the web-services for Android, I-Phone & I-pad that are using Sql Azure as centralized database to maintain same data for all (Web, Android, I-Phone & I-Pad). So I need increases in instance as load increases.

Comment: Then you're ready to go with Cloud Services, but you need to keep in mind the limitations. Take a look at amheds answer. Cloud Services must remain stateless. Never persist data on the machine itself, update the Cloud Service itself and not the files itself (Web Deploy).

Answer (score 1):

Cloud instances are stateless, this means that anything that you've stored on the local storage for the virtual machines can and will be deleted on the event of a node failure, or a system upgrade, or even a new deployment of a package that you upload.

A couple of things you can do:

1. If you need to add additional files or configurations to your project upon deployment, then make use of the OnStart() to perform it. This assures than on each deployment or failure restore you get back the same environment you always had.
2. To avoid losing your source code I recommend you setup source control and integrate it with you cloud instance implementation. You can either do this with Git or with Team Foundation Service (checkout tfspreview.com)
3. If you need to store files on the server such as assets or client-updated media, consider using Azure Blob Storage. Blob storage is replicated both locally on the datacenter and geo-replicated to other datacenters if you choose to do so.

Hope that helps